# How can I set a player height limit when inside a collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a large transparent water cube object that has a box collider with trigger **on** and when I enter it my main player movement script is disabled and my water movement script is enabled. I can move up and down while inside the water collider but the problem is that when I move up, I can move all the way up so that basically I'm standing on top of the water which should be impossible (during this, I am still in the trigger).

To fix this I added a second box collider to my water which is **disabled** on `Start` and a collider script so that the second collider turns **off** and **on** based on my player movements. This works great on its own but the problem is that when I want to climb out of the water, etc, it makes it very difficult because for every additional water mechanic that I want such as climbing out of the water, I need to add workaround code for the second collider and it just looks so messy and over complicated and sometimes it doesn't work right.

I can't use a combination of Raycasts because they don't work inside colliders so I don't know of anything else.

```
void Update()
{
    int waterMask = 1 << 8;
 
    bool rayDetect = Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up * 1f, transform.forward, 0.5f, waterMask);
 
    if (!rayDetect)
    {
        swimUpwardsToSurfaceSpeed = 0f; // prevent player from moving upwards any further
        Debug.Log("Can't move");
    }
}
```

I was trying to do something like in the photo below where once the red Raycast no longer detects the waterMask, stop the player from moving up, but no matter how I approach it there's no results.

[image]

Comment: Since getting in and out of water isn't in real life a can do / can't do thing you might want to consider a more gentle approach, like using rigidbodies and physics materials. This would also allow you to apply differnt levels of gravity in / out / moving to & from the water. Additionally it would free you from having to raycast all the time - just let the physics engine handle it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the standard in-built character controller component? Also my bad, by "getting in and out of the water", I meant like in a pool for example where you lift yourself up out of the edge of the pool etc

Comment: Sure, I get the in / out thing. Unfortunately there's no way to do this with stock code. I've used those controllers before and they're great for learning but always ended up with writing new code because Unity's examples are excellent but they are often overcomplicated to show off the features of the engine so that they're not easy to adapt. I think what you're asking for is not too tricky though, take a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html